# GCP Point in time recovery log storage to buckets

Tags: mysql-5.7, google-cloud-sql

GCP now offers storing binary logs in Cloud Storage instead of on your MySQL disk, but for older instances, you need to disable and re-enable binary logs to start storing them in Cloud Storage.

My DB is very critical and has high availability and read replicas attached to it. Google doesn't seem to let you disable binary logs on instance with HA and replicas attached, does anyone know of a way to move binary logs to Cloud Storage without compromising the HA (i.e. turning it off)?

I've tried disabling the binary logs through the GCP UI, but I have yet to try it through the CLI as it's a disruptive process if it goes through.

Comment: The logs are part of replication. You must disable those features to reconfigure the logs.